# rezise icon label with size proprety

Tags: angular, icons

i have a request , i want to redesign my icon label and i want to add to my componenent the size proprety

this is my icon-label.component.ts

```
  import {
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  Component,
  Input,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'mae-icon-label',
  templateUrl: 'icon-label.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class IconLabelComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() icon: string
  @Input() color: string
  @Input() iconPosition: string

  public computedClass: string

  ngOnInit() {
    this.computedClass = this.color ? `color--${this.color}` : `iconLabel--default`
  }
}
```

my icon-label.html:

```
    <div class="iconLabel {{computedClass}}">
  <div class="mi__wrapper">
    <i class="mi {{icon}}  "
       *ngIf="!iconPosition || iconPosition === 'left'">
    </i>
    <span class="iconLabel__Label"><ng-content></ng-content></span>
    <i class="mi {{icon}}"
       *ngIf="iconPosition === 'right'">
    </i>
  </div>
</div>
```

and my icon-label.scss:

```
    .iconLabel {
  @extend .label-5;
  padding: 6px 10px;
}

.iconLabel--default {
  @include font-color;
}
```

and i want add a size proprey for if the user write proprety small 
my class icon add this mi mi-user mi-2x for exemple

and i want my tag html is like that

```
<mae-icon-label icon="mi-user" [size]="large">Label</mae-icon-label>
```

how can be have that ?

thanks

Comment: Please try making correct sentences. I honestly didn't understand a single thing you wrote ...

Comment: excuse me I don't speak English I'm French

Comment: ça tombe bien, moi aussi ! explique moi rapidement en français ce que tu souhaites, et je pourrais t'aider, ou du moins essayer

Comment: I want try to add a propriety size in my component just that

Comment: a super!!! en gros j'ai un composant déjà créé qui s'appelle icon label et qui permet d'afficher un icon suivi de son label a cote et je veux changer la façon don mes utilisateur programme leur logiciel en précisant la taille pour l'icon et le label change de taille suivant ce que l'utilsateur sa spécifier

Comment: normalement ma balise se fait comme ça <mae-icon-label icon="mi-user">Label</mae-icon-label> et je veux ajouter la propriété size qui permettra a mon icon et mon label de prendre la taille défini selon ce que je lui ai spécifier a savoir Small médium ou large

Comment: Je vois, je te poste une réponse dans la minute, il me faut du template, bouge pas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your comment, here is your solution

**FOR THE HTML**

```
<div class="iconLabel {{size}}">
  <div class="mi__wrapper">
    <i class="mi {{icon}}  "
       *ngIf="!iconPosition || iconPosition === 'left'">
    </i>
    <span class="iconLabel__Label"><ng-content></ng-content></span>
    <i class="mi {{icon}}"
       *ngIf="iconPosition === 'right'">
    </i>
  </div>
</div>
```

**FOR THE COMPONENT**

```
  import {
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  Component,
  Input,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'mae-icon-label',
  templateUrl: 'icon-label.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class IconLabelComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() icon: string
  @Input() color: string
  @Input() iconPosition: string
  @Input() size: string

  public computedClass: string

  ngOnInit() {
    this.computedClass = this.color ? `color--${this.color}` : `iconLabel--default`
  }
}
```

**CALL IT WITH**

```
<mae-icon-label icon="mi-user" [size]="'large'">Label</mae-icon-label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.iconLabel {
  @extend .label-5;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  &__large{
    height:75px;
    width: 75px;
  }
}

.iconLabel--default {
  @include font-color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## **css code**

```
    .iconLabel {
  @extend .label-5;
  padding: 6px 10px;
}

.iconLabel--default {
  @include font-color;
}


.iconLabel--size {
  @include font-color;
  font-size: 5em;
  &__large{
    font-size: 15em;
  }
}
```

## **html code**

```
   <div class="iconLabel {{computedClass}} {{size}}" >
  <div class="mi__wrapper">
    <i class="mi {{icon}}"
       *ngIf="!iconPosition || iconPosition === 'left'">
    </i>
    <span class="iconLabel__Label {{size}}"><ng-content></ng-content></span>
    <i class="mi {{icon}}"
       *ngIf="iconPosition === 'right'">
    </i>
  </div>
</div>
```

## **typescript code**

```
import {
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  Component,
  Input,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'mae-icon-label',
  templateUrl: 'icon-label.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class IconLabelComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() icon: string
  @Input() color: string
  @Input() iconPosition: string
  @Input() size: string

  public computedClass: string

  ngOnInit() {
    this.computedClass = this.color ? `color--${this.color}` : `iconLabel--default`
    //this.computedClass = this.size  ? `size--${this.size}` : `iconLabel--size`
  }

}
```